# Swift ternary syntax error

Tags: swift, ternary-operator

I used to program in Objective-C all the time and I am new to Swift. This error Xcode gives me really confuse me.

```
func renderBufferAreaBAUp(yOffset: CGFloat, amount: CGFloat, ifLeft: Bool)
{     
        var topViewIndexForIndexAdjust = ifLeft?leftTopIndex:rightTopIndex
}
```

On this line I intended to use ternary. leftTopIndex and rightTopIndex are both Int type. However Xcode gives me those on this particular line,

Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
Expected expression

Can anybody tell me what those mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Swift error messages are frequently cryptic and not helpful.  Your real problem is that Swift needs some space around the `?` and `:`.

```
var topViewIndexForIndexAdjust = ifLeft ? leftTopIndex : rightTopIndex
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use blanks to separate operands and operators:

```
var topViewIndexForIndexAdjust = ifLeft ? leftTopIndex : rightTopIndex
                                       ^ ^            ^ ^
```

Swift is very strict on that - even this apparently correct line of code:

```
let val =12
```

generates a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with the cryptic **Swift error messages for Ternary operators**

Error 1

```
incrementValue = incrementValue == 0?1:incrementValue //errors saying add ";", consecutive statements must be separated by ";"
```

Error 2

```
incrementValue = incrementValue = 0 ? 1 : incrementValue //error - Assigning a variable to itself
```

Correct one is - WITH SPACES and WITH ==

```
incrementValue = incrementValue == 0 ? 1 : incrementValue //worked
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    return episodes == nil ? .movie : .tvShow
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! Would be nice with an explanation of your answer and not just code.

Comment: This is not an answer. I flagged it but anusha.V did a bad job and did not remove it. anusha.V should therefore be flagged and removed.